# Question using track changes

Tags: enumerate, itemize, trackchanges

I have the following problem: I submitted a manuscript, where I have to use track changes, but, I have to delete a list of process, using the enumerate environment:

So, I tried the following:

```
\delete{
\begin{enumerate}
\item first
\item second
\end{enumerate}
}
```

but it didn't work. Therefore I did the following instead:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item \deleted{first}
\item \delted{second}
\end{enumerate}
```

And that works. The problem, is when I want to check the final process, considering `\usepackage[final]{changes}` it does not compile. What should I do? There is a possibility to delete the enumerate environment automatically (using track changes)?

Best regards